# Simplest way to setAtributte on href link in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I'm building a small webpage that serves as a Database gestor in pure JSP. I want that, when you click a href link, there's a session atributte set to the name of a table of the database to dispatch all tables with the same code:

```
<body>
    <h1><%="Logistics"%></h1>
    <br/>
    <a href="insert.jsp"><%session.setAttribute("table","product");%>Products</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="insert.jsp"><%session.setAttribute("table","supplier");%>Suppliers</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="insert.jsp"><%session.setAttribute("table","order");%>Orders</a>
</body>
```

What I wants looks something like this. This works but obviously is always order that gets stored. I want pure JSP with no servlet or other dispatcher. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was pretty easy:

On jsp with the link:

```
<a href="insert.jsp?val=product">Products</a>
```

On the receiver just retrieve as:

```
<%=request.getParameter("val")%>
```